# Optimal ratio sample frequency to low-pass

Tags: matlab, filter, lowpass-filter

What is the desired ratio of the low-pass cut frequency to the sampling frequency when designing a digital low-pass filter using MATLAB?

I am trying to filter at `fc=10` Hz a signal sampled at `fs=20` kHz, but I am having some troubles in designing a stable FIR or IIR filter.

I can down-sample the signal, but I would like to know if there is a rule of thumb to design an efficient digital filter in terms of the ratio `fc/fs`. Or a way to obtain a stable filter keeping `fc/fs` as low as possible (avoiding downsampling).

Comment: I think that you should read the "Nyquist-Shannon sampling theorem"

Comment: Why? This is not relevant for this problem ...

Comment: I though you would like to determine the lowest possible `fc` without altering too much your original signal (avoiding downsampling)

Comment: No, fc is fixed, I just would like to know what is the minimum and maximum value recommened for fc/fs when designing a digital filter

Comment: I dont understand how your FIR can get unstable? Is it not the property of a FIR that they are always stable? Sure 10Hz with FS of 20kHz is a quite narrow filter but it should be possible (with a very high order). Have a look at `firpm`

Comment: Do you have a specific number of coefficients for your filter? Please be more specific, do you want a FIR or a IIR?

Comment: And describe your *troubles*: do you have error messages, what happens, show your code, show it's results compared to what you expect.

Comment: For the time being, I'm using the function butter, which should design a Butterworth IIR filter. If I don't decimate my original signal, even if I increase the filter order, either I receive a warning message saying that a matrix (which is presumably built during the computation of the filter coefficients) is badly conditioned or the filtered signal contains all zeros or extremely large values (10^100 or higher). I need to understand why this happens. If I decimate the signal by 100 - resulting signal is sampled 200 Hz - the filter works much better and I obtain a reasonably filtered signal

Comment: You should add the code which you used to generate the filter coefficients and edit the question by excluding the comment of the fir. In general, if you have a very narrow filter relative to the sampling frequency (also depending on the ripples in the pass/stop band and transition width) the filter order will be high. Estimating it with matlab, with the information given by you, a Butterworth filter should have the order of 7 and a fir filter around ~2800. So as you can see, to be really able to help you we need by far more information about the filter characteristics and what you have tried.

Comment: Thanks, can you suggest a good read about this? I don't have (clearly and unfortunately) a good signal processing background and would like to get more info about what MATLAB does when desiging a Butterworth or FIR filter. I didn't find references within the MATLAB Help. Thanks.

Comment: Matlab has a nice pdf as a starting point: [Digital Filters with MATLAB](https://www.mathworks.com/tagteam/82961_digfilt.pdf).